# How to group list of datas?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have three tables, first is **posts** table and second is **post_users** table and **users**.

The **post_users** table contains the tagged users of a post. It has `post_id` and `user_id` columns.

Below is my working code:

```
DB::table('posts')
->select(
    'posts.id AS post_id',
    'posts.likes AS post_likes',
    'post_user.user_id AS tagged_users'
)
->join('post_user', 'post_user.post_id', 'posts.id')
->orderBy('posts.created_at', 'DESC')
->get();
```

The left side is the result of the above code, I just want to ask how to achieve the desired result? I would appreciate Eloquent answers too.
[image]

Comment: >     'post_user.user_id AS tagged_users'
Directly selecting an ID from the joined table with no aggregation causes duplicates based on that join matches.
I would make it with 2 separate simple and fast queries. 1st as you have made it but just aggregating the user-id from the pivot and 2nd to fetch all users  with all the user ids collected at the 1st.
After that you have just 1 loop over the posts to map the users from the results of the 2nd..

Comment: @Svetoslav so it's impossible to achieve this in one query. Can you share to me your suggested answer codes Sir below so that I could accept it if it helps.

Comment: why you don't use eloquent relationships, you can do it with the `with()` method.

Comment: @No.The.Hi can you show to me Sir how to do it in *Eloquent* way? that is also my reason I switch to query builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for using `laravel-eloquent` follow the below way:

at the first, set relation between post and tag in their models, of course, this related to
your Database analysis:

1. if your relationship is one to many:

```php
// Post Model
public function tags()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Tag');
}
// Tag Model
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Post');
}
```

2. or your relationship is many to many:

```php
// Post Model
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Tag');
}
// Tag Model
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Post');
}
```

at last, when you want to get posts with their self tags, you just enough do this:

```php
Post::with('tags')->get();
```

try this way!

for more information read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#introduction).